# Incorrectly labelled albums in Apple Music

Tags: itunes, music, apple-music

I sometimes come across albums in Apple Music whose tracks are incorrectly labelled. For instance, the second track of [this album](https://itunes.apple.com/in/album/classic-moods/853150021) is entirely incorrect. Similarly, the first three tracks of [this album](https://itunes.apple.com/in/album/vidwan-music-of-south-india-songs-of-the-carnatic-tradition/168749381) are permuted.

If I download the album then I can change the song info in my library. But, is there any way to let Apple know that they have their songs incorrectly labelled, so that the album data can be corrected in Apple Music itself?

Comment: It's possible that the problem is not with Apple's database - it may be in the catalog/meta data that the music publisher supplied. It's not unusual to see this on CDs. I'd suggest: [`Don't Worry Be Happy`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-diB65scQU)

Comment: @Seamus I suppose you’re right :)

Answer (score 1):

*Pulling down the comment above, since it satisfactorily answered my question, and it seems this question will not be receiving more activity anytime soon.*

---

> It's possible that the problem is not with Apple's database - it may be in the catalog/meta data that the music publisher supplied. It's not unusual to see this on CDs. I'd suggest: [`Don't Worry Be Happy`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-diB65scQU) – [Seamus](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/149366/seamus) [Mar 2 '19 at 5:08](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352775/incorrectly-labelled-albums-in-apple-music#comment464509_352775)